# TrackBar при использовании LibVLCSharp

Tags: c#

Пишу плеер под определенные нужды. Использую LibVLCSharp.
Реализовал проигрывани, паузу, стоп открытие файла, громкость и т.д.

```
private void Pause_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Обработка клавиши Pause
        _mp.Pause();           
    }

    private void Stop_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Обработка клавиши Stop
        _mp.Stop();
    }

    private void Vol_trackBar_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _mp.Volume = vol_trackBar.Value;
    }
```

Ни как не могу понять, как реализовать используя LibVLCSharp, перематывание медиа с помощью trackBar.

```
private void Media_trackBar_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _mp.Position = 
    }
```

Может кто поделится примером или наводку даст на документацию. У меня не получилось найти.
Спасибо.

Comment: Какого текста? Может быть перематывает медиа?

Comment: Эм, посмотрел я исходники библиотеки, и все что могу посоветовать, не использовать это свойство для указания позиции медиа. Используйте свойство Time.

Comment: Да ошибся, медиа конечно). Но даже со свойством Time не работает.

Comment: Я не могу понять логику перемотки. Многие цепляют таймер. Для чего? Вот поэтому может есть какой готовый пример, с комментариями.

Comment: Сначала обратись к медиа, узнай его длину, потом задай максимальное значение трекбара от длины медиа, и потом его уже перематывай.